# Installing boost on 12.04- have ran "sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev"- now what?

Tags: 12.04, c++, boost

I want to install the boost libraries on Ubuntu 12.04 so I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

but now searching for a folder named "boost" I cannot seem to find where the files have been installed? Do I have to run some sort of bjam command now or something? I am expecting to see some sort of boost folder hierarchy and then all the header and source files for the boost libraries?

Comment: Check ` /usr/local/boost_x_xx_x`

Comment: try **dpkg -L <package-name>**

Comment: Look for it at <code>/usr/include/c++/4.8/boost</code>.

Comment: Do you have an Ubuntu system where Boost headers provided by the official Boost packages for Ubuntu are located there? That's not where they usually go.

Answer (score 6):

Boost header files are in `/usr/include/boost`.

When you install [libboost-all-dev](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libboost-all-dev)[image], a number of [other specific packages are installed as dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-all-dev).

These packages' *also* provide libraries and headers through an indirect mechanism. They declare packages with version numbers in their names as dependencies, and *those* packages are the ones that actually contain the library binaries and header files.

For example, [libboost-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-dev)[image] is one of the packages installed as a dependency of `libboost-all-dev`.

`libboost-dev` [declares just one package as a dependency](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-dev). In 12.04, this package is [libboost1.46-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost1.46-dev)[image]

`libboost1.46-dev` [has dependencies too](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost1.46-dev) but its main purpose is to provide files directly. You can see these [in its file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libboost1.46-dev/filelist).

Boost header files have a `.hpp` extension. (Note that just `.h` is common for most other C++ libraries.) Many `.hpp` files are listed in [`libboost1.46 -dev`'s file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libboost1.46-dev/filelist):

```
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators_fwd.hpp
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/framework/accumulator_base.hpp
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/framework/accumulator_concept.hpp
  ....
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/minmax.hpp
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/minmax_element.hpp
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string.hpp
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp
  ....
/usr/include/boost/aligned_storage.hpp
/usr/include/boost/any.hpp
/usr/include/boost/archive/add_facet.hpp
/usr/include/boost/archive/archive_exception.hpp
/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_archive.hpp
  ....
```

...and so forth.

You'll notice all those files are inside `/usr/include/boost`.

---

To find this information, I used [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), the online Ubuntu packages database.

People interested in finding specific information about what files are provided by Boost packages in their Ubuntu release, what packages provide them, and where they will be located on disk once installed can find that there.

Or, to get you started, [here's a query that shows the `libboost-all-dev` package entries for all currently supported Ubuntu releases (and several others)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost-all-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

I got that by searching under *Search package directories*, changing *Distribution* to "any," and using `libboost-all-dev` as the search keyword.

[image]